# How to replicate this button in CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am trying to create a CSS theme switcher button like below.  The top image shows what I have so far and the bottom image shows what I am trying to create.

I am not the best at this stuff I am more of a back-end coder.  I could really use some help.

I have a live demo of the code here http://dabblet.com/gist/2230656

Just looking at what I have and the goal image, some differences.

- I need to add a gradient
- The border is not right on mine
- Radius is a little off
- Possibly some other stuff?

Also here is the code...it can be changed anyway to improve this, the naming and stuff could be improved I am sure but I can use any help I can get.

HTML

```
<div class="switch-wrapper">
    <div class="switcher left selected">
        <span id="left">....</span>
    </div>
    <div class="switcher right">
        <span id="right">....</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* begin button styles */

.switch-wrapper{
    width:400px;
    margin:220px;
}

.switcher {
    background:#507190;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    position:relative;
}

#left, #right{  
    width:17px;
    height:11px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-5px;
    margin-left:-8px;
    font: 0/0 a;

}
#left{
    background-image: url(http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/images/switcher.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
#right{
    background-image: url(http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/images/switcher.png);
    background-position: -0px -19px;
}


.left, .right{
    width: 30px; height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #3C5D7E;
}

.left{
    border-radius: 6px 0px 0px 6px;
}
.right{
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 -6px
}

.switcher:hover,
.selected {
    background: #27394b;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4),
     inset 0 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6),
      inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a combination of border-radius rules for each browser. However, I find this to be way too tedious for small images like that. Do a .png or .jpg sprite, then set the background-position on :hover and :active

For example:

```
#right { background: url() top right; }
#right:hover { background-position: center right; }
#right:active { background-position: bottom right; }

#left { background: url() top left; }
#left:hover { background-position: center left; }
#left:active { background-position: bottom left; }
```

Okay, here is some modification done with css.

dabblet.com/gist/2231617

Comment: Did you see the demo?  I have already done most of it in CSS, I do not want to use an image I have done that already, I am converting to CSS.    I have it working already, I need to modify it to look more like my example image.  I see what you are saying though, I don't even have a good PSD for all the states though

Comment: Yes, I saw your demo. As I said, this is a lot of work to do in css compared to a sprite... I'll go ahead and modify your code for you. Thanks for the downvote. Sheesh!

Comment: Haha okay, my apologies. I thought that was you with the downvote. :) Check my update.

Comment: Great, thanks that's deff. a lot closer now.  Here it is with colors changed http://dabblet.com/gist/2231573

Comment: Excellent! I just modded the colors but you beat me to it. :) Here's an update with cross-browser border-radius action. http://dabblet.com/gist/2231617

Answer (score 3):

This button can be implemented in pure CSS, without any external images:

http://jsfiddle.net/canassa/weABj/4/

### Beware that using a pure CSS has a few drawbacks:

#### IE10

Everything should render perfectly.

#### IE9

Gradients stops working.

#### IE8

Border-radius stops working.

#### IE7

Hell breaks loose

Comment: Yep... go with sprites for small stuff like this! Way less code, way less fuss.

Answer (score 0):

Replace...

```
#left{
    background-image: url(http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/images/switcher.png);
    background-position: 0px px;
}
#right{
    background-image: url(http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/images/switcher.png);
    background-position: -0px -19px;
}
```

with...

```
#left{
    background-image: url(http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/images/switcher.png);
    background-position: -0px -19px;
}

#right{
    background-image: url(http://www.codedevelopr.com/assets/images/switcher.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px;   
}
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/Sz7dZ/)